# How to make LXDE menu (for Lubuntu) bigger?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I'm trying to see if there's a way to make the Lubuntu [start] menu bigger.

For reference, I'm not referring to the LXPanel itself, but rather the menu that shows up when you click the leftmost button on the panel (i.e. NOT the menu for shut-down options).

I've tried tweaking with the options it has in the preferences, but nothing has helped so far.

There HAS to be a way to just be able to resize the menu in a way that makes it cover more than it's oddly small height and width. Even if the menu just shows a bunch of links, that size it too small.

As someone who treats usability with utmost importance, this is a considerable pet-peeve for me.

To make it clearer:

I want to be able to configure not only the menu's height & width, but it's padding and margins as well.

Isn't there a file I can just play around with?

Comment: Your Lubuntu version is ... ? Is the rest of your screen satisfactory? Is the start menu the only concern?

Comment: Can you not post a screenshot? Use `scrot -d 5` or `scrot -d 10` to get a snap of the menu.

Comment: Don't make people view videos when you can easily provide information here. You may get less help that way. Now, from I could see, things appear normal. Which is why I asked if your issue is **only** with the start menu or with your system font size in general. Let's just answer that first and then go into things like padding, margins, etc

Comment: @DKBose While I agree with your advice, why would you ask for version? I mean, that sounds rhetorical. Obviously I'm ignorant on the matter, and I understand you're trying to help, but really? To answer the question: yes, it's ONLY on the menu where I'm having this issue. Everything else is fine. I've already adjusted it enough.

Comment: The reason for asking for your version, very very obviously, is that things change between versions. Otherwise, there wouldn't be versions.